# Converting from Python to C#

Tags: c#, python

I am having a bit of trouble converting this little class from Python to C#, could anyone help me please?

So far I have this:

```
public class objDict
{
    public objDict(Dictionary<object, object> obj)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<object, object> kvp in obj)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

For the rest I have no idea what to do.. I know just a little bit about Python 
Here's the class:

```
class objDict(object):

    def __init__(self, obj):
        for k, v in obj.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                setattr(self, _to_str(k).title(), objDict(v))
            else:
                setattr(self, k, v)

    def __getitem__(self, val):
        return self.__dict__[val]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{%s}' % str(', '.join('%s : %s' % (k, repr(v)) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.iteritems()))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have so far? Also, why not just use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What is the class intended to do?

Comment: I am trying to convert this https://github.com/ozon/python-bf3stats/blob/master/bf3stats/api.py#L74 from Python to C# I have done the most part, I'm only stuck at the class that I posted..

Comment: Looking at that Python code, it seems what you actually want to do is deserialize JSON into an object graph. Check if any of the answers here help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+deserialize+json

Comment: It looks like you want an `Expando` object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like:

```
class objDict : Dictionary<object, object>
{
    // __init__
    public objDict(IDictionary obj = null)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (DictionaryEntry kv in obj)
        {
            if (kv.Value is IDictionary)
            {
                // Not sure if it should be CultureInfo.InvariantCulture or CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                this.Add(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(kv.Key.ToString()), new objDict((IDictionary)kv.Value));
            }
            else
            {
                this.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    // __getitem__
    public object this[object key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this[key];
        }
    }

    // __repr__
    public string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", this.Select(p => string.Format("{0} : {0}", p.Key, p.Value)));
    }
}
```

I'll say that I don't see anything "better" than a classical `Dictionary<object, object>` if we exclude that inner dictionaries will be shallow-cloned and that there is a useful `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free online tool to automatically convert Python to C#. The results are not perfect but take away a lot of the pain of porting control of flow etc.

https://pythoncsharp.com

```
namespace Namespace {
    
    using System;
    
    public static class Module {
        
        public class objDict
            : object {
            
            public objDict(object obj) {
                foreach (var _tup_1 in obj) {
                    var k = _tup_1.Item1;
                    var v = _tup_1.Item2;
                    if (v is dict) {
                        setattr(this, _to_str(k).title(), objDict(v));
                    } else {
                        setattr(this, k, v);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            public virtual object @__getitem__(object val) {
                return this.@__dict__[val];
            }
            
            public virtual object @__repr__() {
                return String.Format("{%s}", ", ".join(from _tup_1 in this.@__dict__.Chop((k,v) => (k, v))
                    let k = _tup_1.Item1
                    let v = _tup_1.Item2
                    select String.Format("%s : %s", k, repr(v))).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```